# clearing cookies and site-data in webview for both android and ios in react-native

Tags: typescript, react-native, cookies, webview, clear-site-data

I want to clear off some site data which is getting stored on the webview I am using. I read about RCTNetworking, which looks likea solution for iOS. I was not able to successfully implement it. The imports were giving an issue. What could be another possible way to go about this?